# source maps not displaying after mixpanel installation

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular6, mixpanel

My console (in both Dev and prod environments when running localhost:4200) is logging index.js lineNumber instead of component.ts lineNumber. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKbS8.png)

I'm also getting the following mixpanel error in the console upon visiting the website on my domain on the web:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aqf8.png)
Yesterday I put mixpanel on all my buttons. My mixpanel.service.ts file:

```
import * as mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

export class MixpanelService {

  constructor() {
    mixpanel.init('MY_TOKEN');
  }

  track(eventName: string) {
    mixpanel.track(eventName);
  }    
}
```

Throughout my code I've used mixpanel in the following way - component.html file will have a button, in which i'll throw in a click listener:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="mixpanel('saidNoInsteadOfSilenceAndHitSubmitOnCantForm')">Submit</button>
```

and in the component.ts file i'll throw in a function I name mixpanel():

```
constructor(private mixpanelService: MixpanelService) { }


  mixpanel(eventName: string) {
    this.mixpanelService.track(eventName);
  }
```

Sourcemaps seem to be enabled, my tsconfig.json file (look at sourceMap):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get it back to how it was working before? Where my console.logs would give me the component and the line number? Also how do I get rid of the mixpanel error?

Comment: The browser is executing the packaged output which is written into a single source file using webpack. In order to gain further debug information about actual sources you need to leverage so called source maps. This is a piece of metadata for each file that gets merged into the webpack output so that the dev tools in your browser can resolve your actual source of the transpiled code. Frankly, I don't have much experience with Angular, so you'd have to look around yourself on how to enable source maps.

Comment: By the looks of it I've had source maps enabled all along. Look at the last code block i just added for my tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 1):

Can't really say about the maps part as I'm not familiar with Angular either, but the 503 errors that you're seeing from Mixpanel requests look to be CORS related.

[The Mixpanel help center has an article on this.](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004511086-CORS-errors)

Also, [there's a new community site](https://community.mixpanel.com/topics/community+help.html) where you can ask follow up questions.